# Apartment number before or after house number and street

Tags: american-english, letter-writing

When writing an address, I wonder which comes first, the apartment number, or the house number and street name? Thanks!

For example:

> 1234 Charles ST APT A
>
> Hollywood, CA 54321

or

> APT A, 1234 Charles ST
>
> Hollywood, CA 54321

Comment: Go to the [USPS Web site](https://www.usps.com/), click on Look Up a ZIP Code, and enter an address. The result will be displayed in Standard Form, which will be: `1234 CHARLES ST APT A`

Comment: @Gnawme: Why isn't the most specific foremost?

Comment: That's not how the [USPS sorts mail.](http://www.fact-fun.com/PostOffice/SortingTheMail.php/) It goes from ZIP Code and gets sorted more specifically from there.

Comment: I write mine as 434B W 48th Street.

Comment: In Italy we use: 'street', 'city', 'region', 'CAP', but I have never understood why.

Comment: @Carlo_R.: What is CAP?

Comment: CAP is ZIP code (Codice di Avviamento Postale).

Comment: vote to migrate elsewhere

Comment: @cornbreadninja If you run your address through the USPS ZIP Code search, what does the Standard Form look like?

Comment: @Gnawme it changes it to 434 W 48th Street Apt. B, but I suspected as much.

Answer (score 4):

This depends on the postal service to which you're sending your mail.  You are asking about sending mail in the US, so use the USPS website, as [Gnawme recommended](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76025/apartment-number-before-or-after-house-number-and-street#comment148091_76025).

The British, Canadian, New Zealand, Indian, etc., postal services may do things differently.  This is not a language question, but a policy question.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, you would go from most to least in terms of specificity. IOW, I would use

> Apt A, 1234, Charles St.,
>
> Hollywood, CA 54321.

But that's me. Seeing as to how Americans prefer mm-dd-yy to dd-mm-yy, I won't be surprised if CMoS or similar recommends that the apartment number be inserted somewhere weird :)

Comment: Thanks! Where is your way widely used?

Comment: @Tim The rest of the world: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country . I see that a couple of Americans don't like my answer :D

Answer (score -2):

The Post Office likes you to write most-specific to least-specific (so, apartment first), but everyone actually writes the street address first.

Comment: Thanks! Why is that difference?

Comment: The Post Office likes to read addresses from bottom to top (so country, postal code, state, city...), because they *route* things that way.  Why everyone does it "wrong", I cannot say.

Comment: Actually USPS uses the first way in my question.

Comment: That's not true of all post offices.  The US Postal Service, for instance, tends to put apartment on line 2.